# Prevent access to custom login page for logged in users

Tags: customization

I have created a custom login page, different from the default login page. The custom login page is working flawlessly without any errors and redirects after login to a specified page.

However, I need to prevent access to this login page when users are logged in to wordpress and for any reason attempt to view the login page again. The user should be redirected to the home page or any other page I specify. I have used the get_queried_object() function to return the page object's post title element ('Login' in this use case).

The conditional check that should force a redirect when the $page_title = 'Login' as shown in code below does nothing as I can still access the login page even when I am signed into the site.

```
function redirect_login_page() {
   $page_object = get_queried_object();
   $page_title = get_queried_object()->post_title;
   $login_page  = home_url( '/login/' );
   $home_page  = home_url();
   $nf_page  = home_url('404');
   $page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
            wp_redirect($login_page);
            exit;
       }
    }
    else
    {
      if( ($page_viewed == "wp-login.php" or $page_viewed == "login.php" OR $page_title == 'Login') && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
      wp_redirect($home_page);
      exit;
     }
    }
}

add_action('init','redirect_login_page');
```

How may this redirect be enforced for already logged in users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect as early as possible. The best hook for this is `template_redirect`. Check for 2 conditions - if the page is 'login' and user is logged in:

```
function redirect_login_page() {

    if( is_page( 'login' ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_login_page' );
```

Comment: Pure code dumps are not recommended, it's preferred to explain things  as well. Thanks

Comment: I understand this, but the code is pretty self-explanatory and looks like the author is developer, technically skilled enough to read and understand it. However, I've added a simple explanation.

Comment: yes better, thanks - Other visitors to this site will read your answer as well ;-) PS: I noticed your answer because someone had flagged it as low quality, possibly because of the missing explanation.

Comment: @IhorVorotnov, it appears I was attempting to plugin to the `init` action hook, which is triggered after WordPress has finished loading and therefore, it is too late to do a redirect right? Hooking into the `template_redirect` action hook also works, when the get_queried_object() function is used to the get the page's post_title, and checking for `if($page_title == 'Login') as per my use case, highlited above. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Terungwa, yes, `init` is too late for redirects. Also, I don't really see a reason to check for title (as it may change over time), when you have url slug (there's a bigger chance it will stay the same for SEO purposes). Anyway, it's for you to decide.